# Modular Arithmetic with higher powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find an integer $0\leq n<1000$ such that the last three digits of $n^{267}$ are $321$.

I have tried this method:

$n^{267}\equiv 321(\text{ mod }1000)$

So, I break it up into two congruences and thought to apply the Chinese remainder theorem.

$n^{267}\equiv n^3\equiv321\equiv 1(\text{ mod }8)$
$n^{267}\equiv n^{67}\equiv321\equiv 71(\text{ mod }125)$

But it's very hard to solve the above congruences. Therefore, I do suspect that there is another method to solve the above congruence. Please help

Comment: @DietrichBurde IMO I don't think it does, unless you want OP to cycle through all  values of $a$ coprime to 1000.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant using it like your hint. Such questions have been posted here already. One need's to find the right one, of course.

Comment: Right, the hard part is "find the right one", esp if we don't know OP's ability (or willingness) to abstract from a slightly different situation.

Comment: Since someone wants to delete this topic, I think we need to open it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $267 \times 3 = 801 = 1 + \phi(1000)$

Can you take it from here?

---

If you want a step-by-step approach:

> Step 1: Show that $ \gcd(n, 1000) = 1$.

$ $

> Step 2: Calculate $ n^{801} \pmod{1000}$ from the given conditions using $ 267 \times 3 = 801$.

$ $

> Step 3: Calculate $ n \pmod{1000}$ applying Euler's Theorem

Answer (score 1):

To solve $n^{67}\equiv71\bmod125$, note $(n^{67})^3\equiv n \equiv71^3\bmod 125$.